# Android совет по fragment

Tags: android

Хочу сделать поиск товара по параметрам.

Предполагается, что во фрагменте будет осуществлять поиск по названию. В этом же фрагменте сразу будут выводится результаты запроса RecyclerView(CardView).

Так как места под фильтры нету, решил что нужно как то сделать, чтобы по свайпу вправо открывалось окно, в котором можно выбирать фильтры.

После этого можно свайпом влево вернуться, где будут результаты применения фильтра.

Вопрос: как можно это реализовать?

2 фрагмента, между которыми будет происходить переключение
либо это сделать в 1 фрагменте, но фильтры будут располагаться в невидимой части, и при свайпе вправо будет происходить перемещение к фильтрам?

Может есть уже готовый способ либо совет?

В качестве примера могу привести Play Market. только нужно спрятать верхнюю часть, где написаны названия разделов. Только я не знаю что это за элемент. Возможно Navigation Drawer Activity, только в горизонтальном виде

P.S. Не кидайте тапками, все когда-то учились...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё-таки лучше сделать чтоб фильтрация была видна на том экране что и список. Делать жест на основную функцию списков, это прям очень жестоко, пользователь может никогда не узнать что фильтрация есть, а после того как сделает, должен помнить, как он фильтровал и фильтровал ли вообще, подумайте над этим. А на вопрос ваш ответить можно только советом, сделать это можно 100500 способами, сколько фантазии хватит

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Фильтров слишком много, для них просто места нет. Может лучше тогда оставить вкладки, чтобы пользователь увидел, что есть фильтры. А по поводу совета, приведите хотя бы основные способы, чтобы я сам копал в определенную сторону

Comment: ну также как в плеймаркете сделайте. 
1.Создайте хедер в списке.

2.Создайте диалог (BottomSheet тоже хорошо будет смотреться)

3.По нажатию на хедер показывайте диалог, от результат выбора сортируйте ваш список, и в хедере показывайте какой фильтр применен.